# Python Dataframe Calculate Daily mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I am having a data frame with hourly power data. I want to compute average daily power.

**My code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'power':np.arange(1.0,9.0)},index=pd.date_range(start='2020-05-04 08:00:00', freq='1h', periods=8))
df['time'] = df.index
df['avgpwr'] = xdf['A'].rolling(2).mean()
df['DailyAvg'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").map(dict(df['avgpwr'].resample('1D').mean()))
```

**Present output:**

```
df = 
                     power               time  avgpwr  DailyAvg
2020-05-04 08:00:00  1.0 2020-05-04 08:00:00     0.0        NaN
2020-05-04 09:00:00  2.0 2020-05-04 09:00:00     1.5        NaN
2020-05-04 10:00:00  3.0 2020-05-04 10:00:00     2.5        NaN
2020-05-04 11:00:00  4.0 2020-05-04 11:00:00     3.5        NaN
2020-05-04 12:00:00  5.0 2020-05-04 12:00:00     4.5        NaN
2020-05-04 13:00:00  6.0 2020-05-04 13:00:00     5.5        NaN
2020-05-04 14:00:00  7.0 2020-05-04 14:00:00     6.5        NaN
2020-05-04 15:00:00  8.0 2020-05-04 15:00:00     7.5        NaN
```

There is something wrong in my calculations and I see NaN only? How to compute the daily energy? Is it just summing the power? do we need to multiply time and how do we do it?

**Expected answer**

```
df = 
                      DailyAvg
2020-05-04 08:00:00   3.9375
2020-05-04 09:00:00   3.9375
2020-05-04 10:00:00   3.9375
2020-05-04 11:00:00   3.9375
2020-05-04 12:00:00   3.9375
2020-05-04 13:00:00   3.9375
2020-05-04 14:00:00   3.9375
2020-05-04 15:00:00   3.9375
```

Comment: This probably doesnt have anything to do with pandas. Can you extract the part that is calculating DailyAvg to begin with? Dont so all calculations on one line, split it up, and you will see where you get your NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try resample transform instead:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Recreate DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'power': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 5.0, 5: 6.0, 6: 7.0, 7: 8.0},
     'time': {0: '2020-05-04 08:00:00', 1: '2020-05-04 09:00:00',
              2: '2020-05-04 10:00:00', 3: '2020-05-04 11:00:00',
              4: '2020-05-04 12:00:00', 5: '2020-05-04 13:00:00',
              6: '2020-05-04 14:00:00', 7: '2020-05-04 15:00:00'},
     'avgpwr': {0: 0.0, 1: 1.5, 2: 2.5, 3: 3.5, 4: 4.5, 5: 5.5, 6: 6.5, 7: 7.5}}
)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.index = df['time']
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=0)
# End Recreate DataFrame


# Resample Transform
df["DailyAvg"] = df['avgpwr'].resample("1D").transform('mean')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                     power                time  avgpwr  DailyAvg
2020-05-04 08:00:00    1.0 2020-05-04 08:00:00     0.0    3.9375
2020-05-04 09:00:00    2.0 2020-05-04 09:00:00     1.5    3.9375
2020-05-04 10:00:00    3.0 2020-05-04 10:00:00     2.5    3.9375
2020-05-04 11:00:00    4.0 2020-05-04 11:00:00     3.5    3.9375
2020-05-04 12:00:00    5.0 2020-05-04 12:00:00     4.5    3.9375
2020-05-04 13:00:00    6.0 2020-05-04 13:00:00     5.5    3.9375
2020-05-04 14:00:00    7.0 2020-05-04 14:00:00     6.5    3.9375
2020-05-04 15:00:00    8.0 2020-05-04 15:00:00     7.5    3.9375
```

---

Specifically the issue with your code is your mapper:

```
dict(df['avgpwr'].resample('1D').mean())
```

```
{Timestamp('2020-05-04 00:00:00', freq='D'): 3.9375}
```

Which will only map exact matches (midnight that day). Which is why none of the hours during the day are converted.

Comment: I appreciate you clearly explaining the mistake in my code. Thanks a ton. Learned something here.